How is ともすれば used in this sentence?

I'm slightly confused on this usage of "ともすれば" here
As far I can see the sentence could be read  as
愛よりも恋よりも本能や肉欲よりも
rather than love, romantic love, instinct and lust...
But how is ともすれば actually used here? Is it modifying ともすれば本能?

This question is similar to: ともすれば～・ともすると～: " a tendency to ~, prone to ~" or "cause and effect"?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In you case, it's almost the same as ひょっとすると. "heavier than 愛, or 恋, or maybe even 本能 or 肉欲".
